# cv::text::OCRTesseract not respecting filters on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract, raspberry-pi3

I am using the [OCRTesseract](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/ddc/classcv_1_1text_1_1OCRTesseract.html) extra module in openCV for text recognition on a raspberry pi model 3. I want it to only detect single, uppercase characters. The following initilization code works perfectly fine on my desktop and laptop:

```
Ptr<OCRTesseract> tess;
tess = OCRTesseract::create(NULL, NULL, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 3, 10);
```

however when run on the run on the raspberry pi it seems to ignore the filters and will often give lowercase characters and symbols. Occasionally giving multiple characters at the same time.
I have tried:

```
tess->setWhiteList("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

to no avail.
Any suggestions? The OCR works fine apart from this issue. Allowing it to detect lowercase letters/symbols is resulting in a lot more false positives than I am happy with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I found it to be a [bug](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751) in tesseract version 4.00.00alpha (which just so happened to be the version I was running on the PI).
Setting the OEM mode to 0 completely fixed the issue. The following initilization code works as intended:

```
Ptr<OCRTesseract> tess;
tess = OCRTesseract::create(NULL, NULL, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the rep needed to comment. My guess would be a faulty installation of tesseract or opencv in your pi considering the fact that it ignores the whitelist and give multiple character when psm is set to 10 (single character).

Can you provide the version of your tesseract and opencv?

If possible, try to save the image as a file then use tesseract from command line to see whether it works properly.

Comment: Tesseract version was 4.00.00alpha. Tests on the command line led towards me finding out that the whitelist is broken in this version unless you set the OEM to 0. Got it working now, cheers

Comment: Glad that you find your problem. Tesseract 4.00.00 is still under active development though so it may be buggy here and there. If possible, try to go for 3.05.01 which is the latest stable version.